# LME error in model.frame.default ... variable lengths differ

Tags: r, nlme

I am trying to run a random effects model with LME. It is part of a larger function and I want it to be flexible so that I can pass the fixed (and ideally random) effects variable names to the lme function as variables. get() worked great for this where I started with lm, but it only seems to throw the ambiguous "Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~var1 + var2 + ID, data = list( : variable lengths differ (found for 'ID')." I'm stumped, the data are the same lengths, there are no NAs in this data or the real data, ...

```
set.seed(12345) #because I got scolded for not doing this previously
var1="x"
var2="y"
exdat<-data.frame(ID=c(rep("a",10),rep("b",10),rep("c",10)),
           x = rnorm(30,100,1),
           y = rnorm(30,100,2))
#exdat<-as.data.table(exdat) #because the data are actually in a dt, but that doesn't seem to be the issue
```

Works great

```
lm(log(get(var1))~log(get(var2)),data=exdat)
lme(log(y)~log(x),random=(~1|ID), data=exdat)
```

Does not work

```
 lme(log(get(var1,pos=exdat))~log(get(var2)),random=(~1|ID), data=exdat)
```

Does not work, but throws a new error code: "Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~var1 + var2 + rfac + exdat, data = list( : invalid type (list) for variable 'exdat'"

```
rfac="ID"
lme(log(get(var1))~log(get(var2)),random=~1|get(rfac,pos=exdat), data=exdat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem seems to be with the nlme package. If you can consider using lme4, the desired results can be obtained by with:

```
lme4::lmer(log(get(var1)) ~ log(get(var2)) + (1 | ID),
       data = exdat)
```